# What is passive voice misuse?

Tags: passive-voice

Observe below a body of an email:-

> I have been directed to send the report on the subject mentioned above. PFA.

On the Grammarly software, it is flagged as **passive voice misuse**. Please enlighten me about the **passive voice misuse**. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what Grammarly thinks: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/active-vs-passive-voice/

Comment: The passive voice has special pluses and minuses.

Since it leaves out the agent (this thing that was done, who did it?), you are not identifying information that the reader may want. But occasionally, you need to be diplomatic by skipping over that very information. In your example, it might be smart for you not to refer to which of your bosses instructed you on this report.